# Cannot access values of explicitly defined array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am fetching an object from the database, and I 'converted' it to array so that I can use foreach on it.

```
$my_obj = (array) json_decode( get_option('my_options') );
```

This gets me array like this when I do a `print_r` on it:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [settings] => stdClass Object (
        [default] => 1 
        [header_title] => Separate title for this one! 
        [header_layout] => header_logo_centered 
        [fixed_header] => 1 
        [sticky_header] => 0 
        [transparent_header_transition] => 1 
        [select_menu] => centered-logo-header 
        [select_second_menu] => left-menu-header 
        [logo] => 
        [retina_logo] => ...wp-content/uploads/2015/12/sample.jpg 
        [retina_logo_width] => 
        [retina_logo_height] => 
        [transparent_logo] => 
        [transparent_retina_logo] => 
        [transparent_retina_logo_width] => 
        [transparent_retina_logo_height] => 
        [background_image] => ...wp-content/uploads/2015/08/audiothumb1.jpg 
        [background_color] => #848484 
        [text_color] => #397509 
        [text_hover_color] => 
        [transparent_text_color] => 
        [transparent_text_hover_color] => #146051 
        [test_select] => test_option_3 
        [test_textarea] => This is a test for textarea....ghghfsd 
        [test_pages_dropdown] => 5452 
        [icon_number] => 1 
        [test_icons_icon_0] => s7-magic-wand 
        [test_icons_value_0] => test2
        )
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [settings] => stdClass Object (
        [default] => 0 
        [header_title] => Test title here... 
        [header_layout] => header_layout_logo_left_magic_background 
        [fixed_header] => 
        [sticky_header] => 
        [transparent_header_transition] => 
        [select_menu] => 
        [select_second_menu] => 
        [logo] => 
        [retina_logo] => 
        [retina_logo_width] => 
        [retina_logo_height] => 
        [transparent_logo] => 
        [transparent_retina_logo] => 
        [transparent_retina_logo_width] => 
        [transparent_retina_logo_height] => 
        [background_image] => 
        [background_color] => 
        [text_color] => 
        [text_hover_color] => 
        [transparent_text_color] => 
        [transparent_text_hover_color] => 
        [test_select] => 
        [test_textarea] => 
        [test_pages_dropdown] => 
        [icon_number] => 0
        )
    )
)
```

Now when I try to do:

```
$my_obj[0]
```

I get

> Notice undefined offset 0 in ....

And I cannot get anything out of it. But when I do a foreach on it, I can access my object just fine, and all its properties.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on in code you haven't shown. There is nothing wrong with what has been provided and it wouldn't give you that error.

Comment: Two possibilities: `0` isn't actually `0` but some character that looks like `0`. Test that with `print_r(array_map('bin2hex', array_keys($my_obj)))`. `0` should show up as `30`. The other explanation is that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve : update the question with an example of json string.

Comment: 0 appears as 30. 0 Should be a number, right? I've tried `print_r(array_map('gettype', array_keys($my_obj)));` and I got `Array ( [0] => string [1] => string )`, could this be the issue?

Comment: No, numbers vs. string indices don't make a difference: https://3v4l.org/M96WN

Comment: `$my_obj = (array) json_decode(...)`. What you probably want is [`json_decode(..., TRUE)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @axiac this did the trick! It converted the object to array (even better than having array of objects). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. `json_decode` converts json to array so need to explicitly define array.
2. For fetching an stdclass object you can pull data by `$object->key`in your case `$my_obj[0]->settings` or you can convert object as array from following code

   ```
   foreach ($object as $value) 
     $array[] = $value->post_id;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectToArray( $object ) {
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ) {
        return $object;
    }
    if( is_object( $object ) ) {
        $object = get_object_vars( $object );
    }
    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}
```

try this function ( for multidimensional obj ) ... and paste here the print_r